# LAMP not working as expected. Can login to phpmyadmin but not edit or do anything on remote

Tags: php, mysql, apache, lamp

Ok, this problem is driving me crazy.

I had IIS 7.0 before in Windows Server 2008 and hosted there 8 wordpress websites. Websites can show from outside without problem, also I could access phpmyadmin. But to modify the wordpress websites was imposible from outside and only can modify them from accessing the webserver from teamviewer. So I decided to change from IIS to Ubuntu 16.04.

Now I have LAMP with PHP7, mysql and apache2.

I uploaded again the websites and also I can access them from outsite. But still there are problems that drive me crazy. These problems are only from outside the webserver. If im logged in the webserver I can make any changes and access everything without problem.

So the situation is like this:

I dont have any problem changing anything and accessing anything if I remotely (with vnc) use the server
I can view the websites from outside without problems
I can login to wp-admin without problem from outside
I can upload photos and install plugins from outside (so I dont think there is a permission problem for /var/www folder)
I cannot update posts on wordpress from outside and after I click update post the post is only saved as draft and the page loads continiously.
On some websites I cannot save theme settings
Installed a clean wordpress and still the same problems (Tried with default theme and with no plugins)
I can access phpmyadmin and login to phpmyadmin from outside, but when I click to open something (like import, users or to view databases) it just says loading and not opens anything else. But I can access also phpmyadmin from the webserver with vnc
On the webserver is open only port 80 and all other ports are blocked with a firewall
Please somebody help me with this.

Comment: This is not really a programming question.   Try ServerFault?

Comment: thanks, was first time i use an asking website